# Difference between "can" and "could" in context

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal, can-modal

Can you please tell me if native speakers of English would sense any difference in meaning beween *can* and *could* in the context below?

> Unfortunately we don't have anyone available who **can** come and fix your laptop.
>
> Unfortunately we don't have anyone available who **could** come and fix your laptop.

Generally I'm aware of when to use *can* and *could*, but in this specific context I can't see any difference between the too. Is there any? Are both perfectly natural?

Comment: I don't think there is any practical difference.

Comment: Just the normal difference where "could" is slightly more formal or polite than "can".